# Using Full-Duplex Serial Port with ASIO (or other libraries) in a Synchronous Manner

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio, asio, full-duplex

I'm working on a project where I need to communicate with a device over a serial port. I've been considering using the ASIO library to handle the communication, but I have a few questions:

1. Is a serial port inherently full-duplex? Can I read from and write to the port simultaneously without any issues?
2. If I use ASIO, can I perform synchronous reads and writes on the same asio::serial_port object from two different threads without using a mutex? Specifically, I want one thread dedicated to reading and another to writing. It's important to note that only one thread will write and one will read, so it is not possible to have multiple readings or writings, but reading and writing at the same time should be possible.
3. If ASIO isn't the best choice for this, are there any other libraries you'd recommend for synchronous serial port communication in C++?

Now, I am protecting the asio::serial_port with a mutex, so only one read or write can occur.
I am using ASIO in a Synchronous Manner.

Comment: 1. Depends on the type of the serial port. [RS485 serial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485), for example, is **not** full duplex.

Comment: @user4581301 Full duplex operation
RS-485, like RS-422, can be made full-duplex by using four wires.[8] Since RS-485 is a multi-point specification, however, this is not necessary or desirable in many cases. RS-485 and RS-422 can interoperate with certain restrictions

Comment: @Jonathan Perhaps I'm old school, but when you have 4 wires you no longer have RS485 and might as well be using RS422.  I've found it better to stick to the lowest common denominator rather than have surprised and upset clients who only have a 2 wire interface at their end.

Comment: @user4581301 that's straight from the wiki you linked. I've never used that particular standard.

Comment: Yup. And I disagree with it. Stick to 2-wire operation or engineer and market the device with a 422 interface.

Answer (score 0):

Asio is already threaded. It uses threads to prevent blocking, which is the library's purpose (Asynchronous Input output). RS232 is, by design, full duplex. The protocol handles sending and receiving at the same time on the port.

Comment: Asio is not threaded. It [allows threading, obviously](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html). However, it will be far easier to use asynchrony than properly coordinating different threads on the same port object.

Comment: @sehe Thanks for the clarification. In any case, I've never used ASIO that didn't set up a background thread to handle read/write operations, so that's where I was confused.

Comment: added an example of single-threaded async full-duplex serial IO in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it the complicated way by synchronizing multi thread access to the IO object:

(todo coming up with complicated example)

### Simpler, Single-Threaded Async

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using sp       = asio::serial_port;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::literals;

struct Example {
    Example(asio::any_io_executor ex, std::string dev) : sp_(ex, dev) {
        readLoop();
    }

    void Send(std::string cmd) {
        std::cerr << "Queue: " << quoted(cmd) << std::endl;
        outbox_.push_back(std::move(cmd));
        if (outbox_.size() == 1)
            writeLoop();
    }

    void Stop() {
        sp_.cancel();
    }

  private:
    void readLoop() {
        asio::async_read_until( //
            sp_, asio::dynamic_buffer(incoming_), "\n", [this](error_code ec, size_t len) {
                std::cerr << "Read: " << len << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
                if (!ec.failed()) {
                    Send("echo: "s + incoming_.substr(0, len));
                    incoming_.erase(0, len);
                    readLoop();
                }
            });
    }
    void writeLoop() {
        if (outbox_.empty())
            return;
        asio::async_write(sp_, asio::buffer(outbox_.front()), [this](error_code ec, size_t len) {
            std::cerr << "Wrote: " << len << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
            if (!ec.failed()) {
                outbox_.pop_front();
                writeLoop();
            }
        });
    }

    asio::serial_port       sp_;
    std::string             incoming_;
    std::deque<std::string> outbox_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    Example          drone(ioc.get_executor(), (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "/dev/stty0"));

    ioc.run_for(30s);

    // not really needed, but to show graceful shutdown
    drone.Stop();
    ioc.run();
}
```

Live Demo:

[image]

Comment: To be complete honest, I don't think I can make the multi-threaded approach work because of [the threadsafety of `asio::serial_port`](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port.html#boost_asio.reference.serial_port.thread_safety): it would mean both threads blocking under the lock. (In case you want to see what I had written - WHICH IS BROKEN CODE: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b5104a6f55e6dd2)